# Could not Input value many times

Tags: c++, variables, input, cin

I just started C++ recently and now I encounter a problem in a very simple program. I was successful inputting part_num and part_des (both type string), but the program skipped part_price and part_quant (type int). I could not enter values for these two last variables.How do I fix this problem? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string part_num;
string part_des;
int part_price;
int part_quant;

cout<<"Please enter the part number: ";
cin>>part_num;
cout<<"\n"<<endl;

cout<<"Please enter the part description: ";
cin>>part_des;
cout<<"\n"<<endl;

cout<<"Please enter the part price: ";
cin>>part_price;
cout<<"\n"<<endl;

cout<<"Please enter the part quantity: ";
cin>>part_quant;
cout<<"\n"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: There is no error, the execution just did not let me inputting the value of price and quantity

Comment: What compiler / IDE are you using?

Comment: You did recompile the program, right?

Comment: I found out that the problem occurs only when I put "Red, aluminum" for my part description. If I still want to leave the description like that, how would I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What Happens

Please test for yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string my_string;
    cout << "enter a string: ";
    cin >> my_string;
    cout << "you have entered: " << my_string << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Results:

```
enter a string: one
you have entered: one
Press any key to continue . . .

enter a string: one two
you have entered: one
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Where is "two"? It remains in stream. When you try to get a number after this, this piece of text is automatically taken as your input, probably it rises an exception and your program suddenly ends.

### How to Fix

Use something like [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string my_string;
    cout << "enter a string: ";
    getline (cin, my_string);
    cout << "you have entered: " << my_string << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

This will eliminate the problem you're having.

```
enter a string: one two
you have entered: one two
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. ( if you don't have whitespaces in there )

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string part_num;
    string part_des;
    int part_price;
    int part_quant;

    cout<<"Please enter the part number: ";
    cin>>part_num;
    cout<<"\n" << part_num <<endl;

    cout<<"Please enter the part description: ";
    cin>>part_des;
    cout<<"\n" << part_des <<endl;

    cout<<"Please enter the part price: ";
    cin>>part_price;
    cout<<"\n" << part_price <<endl;

    cout<<"Please enter the part quantity: ";
    cin>>part_quant;
    cout<<"\n" << part_quant <<endl;
}
```

http://ideone.com/U31pb9

Just give yourself the output right away. To see what you were missing.

Fixed for whitespaces n stuff:

```
int main()
{
    string part_num;
    string part_des;
    int part_price;
    int part_quant;

    cout<<"Please enter the part number: ";
    getline( cin , part_num );
    cout << "\n" << part_num <<endl;

    cout<<"Please enter the part description: ";
    getline( cin , part_des );
    cout<< "\n" << part_des <<endl;

    cout<<"Please enter the part price: ";
    cin >> part_price;
    cout << "\n" << part_price <<endl;

    cout << "Please enter the part quantity: ";
    cin >> part_quant;
    cout << "\n" << part_quant <<endl;
}
```

Also think about using strings for the price and the quant as well and then convert them to integer if you want to keep using getline.

Comment: I found out that the problem occurs when I put "Red, aluminum" for my part description. If I still want to leave the description like that, how would I fix the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it should work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i;
  cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";
  cin >> i;
  cout << "The value you entered is " << i;
  cout << " and its double is " << i*2 << ".\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It obviously works, but has nothing to do with the OP's problem.